# Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity() stops launching activities

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium

I'm basically using the navigation controller from forging titanium ([Nav Controller](http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/forging-titanium/video/27834295)). I'm also trying to launch various web pages with the code below. The issue is that after navigating around the app for a bit, the intents seem to not start activities any more.

Has anyone else ran into a similar issue? If so, how was it resolved?

Thank you for your time

```
exports.openWebPage = function(url) {
    if (Ti.Network.online) {
        if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android') {
            var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
                data: encodeURI(url),
                className: 'com.android.browser.BrowserActivity',
                packageName: 'com.android.browser'
            });
            intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
            Ti.API.info('openWebPage: ' + url);

        }
        else {
            Ti.Platform.openURL(url);
            Ti.API.info('openWebPage: ' + url);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Please establish an internet connection first');
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I appear to have a similar issue after my app goes to sleep and I bring it back. `Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);` just doesn't do anything, no error, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could help this is what happened to me recently when carrying a url from an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse (url));
startActivity (i);
```

URL must start with http:// or https:// otherwise you will get a very nice exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Each of my urls have 'http://' at the front. I should also note that my method (above) will work several times, and then stop until the app is restarted.